# Calculate time differences and sum duration

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a small "app" using tasker on my android phone that am supposed to track my workhours and over/under-time. I have managed to get tasker to send timestamps on the start/end of each workday and are writing them to a google sheet so it gets recorded like:

```
                                     <Not implemented>        <Not implemented>  
 |     A      |       B     |    C     |     D     |    E       |    F    |
 | 2020-01-29 |     07:24   |   16:33  |    00:09  |            | -02:51  | 
 | 2020-01-30 |     07:00   |   12:00  |   -03:00  |            |         |
```

Where the "D" column is the difference between ordinary workhours (8) and actually registred hours.

The "F" column should summarize the "D" column and show the sum of all values.
The data in the three first columns are beeing sent correctly but I cant figure out how to set up formulas so that the values for the "D" column is added and and same thing with the cell in the "F" column. I have been trying to change to different formats and tried creating my own formats to but do not understand how to get it to work.

Comment: Could you please add a sample sheet to illustrate better what you want? I don't understand which calculation are you using to get the `D` and `F` column.

Comment: how did you calculate "00:07" in D column?

Comment: B: Arrived to work
C: Left Work
D: Total hours worked - 8 hours (00:07 is 7 minutes overtime, -03:00 means I left 3 hours early)
F: Should be the sum of all time-durations in D added together

Comment: sorry I had the wrong calculation in "D" in the original post. It is corrected now

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem. It looks like F2 is already a correct sum of column D (00:09 + -03:00 = -02:51). How is this different than what you're trying to do?

Comment: I tried to show this in the description. That part is not implemented yet as I do not know how to do this. I just filled it in to show how I want it to function

Comment: Gotcha. So, all of the calculated cells (column D and F1), you've just done manually so far. Do you have any attempts you've made at the formulas?

Comment: Most guides I found realting this was mentioning just using =SUM() and formatting the source data to time/duration. But when I have tried I only get 00:00 or some error stating that it can't do calculation on text. So the first part of my problem is how exactly to calculate with values in HH:mm format

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems with the answer below. If you're also subtracting out a lunch hour, I'd recommend one more column (insert after Column C, perhaps) containing the amount of time lost each day (lunch hour, doctor appt, etc). Then, the formula in Column E (assuming "time lost" was captured in a new Column D) would change to `=((C1-B1)-D1)-(8/24)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a different result than you in D1. I wonder if you're also accounting for a lunch hour (so subtract 9 instead of 8), but these formulas worked for me:

- in Column D: `=(C1-B1)-(8/24)`
- in Cell F1: `=sum(D1:D2)`

Column D and Cell F1 are formatted as Time > Duration.

Here's the result:
[image: GoogleSheetsTrialRun]

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but I can't replicate the above. If you/someone else have the time to have a look here is the link:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WRaVc5hegWcqAgCo2gpkqJQiCw8-I_rtOZBwyvOuFRg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it possible to apply the formula to the entire D column? so that every new row that gets added is automatically calculated (both D column and F-cell)?

Comment: It looks like Google Sheets is not seeing your data as numbers. When you imported them, it converted them to text. I'm not familiar with "tasker", but you may have to look into the export process to get these fields to export as numbers. Alternatively, you could add a couple more columns to convert them to numbers first using `=TIME(LEFT(B2,2);RIGHT(B2,2);0). Note the use of semi-colons due to how your spreadsheet is set up.

Comment: I made some edits in a copied sheet in the doc you sent.

Comment: As far as applying to the entire column, after you enter the formula into the first cell (D1 in the example above), copy that cell and paste it as far down as you think you'll need it (to the bottom if you like), then edit the formula in cell F1 so that it reflects that range (the "D2" in the formula would become "D200" or wherever you put the end of the range).

Comment: Just one last question, how did you manage to get the first example in your image to work? Even if I open a new sheet and enter two times manually and then format them to time I can't do any calculation. I also formated the target cell to duration.

Comment: That's all I did was well. I wonder if it has to do with the language settings of your sheet (and computer, perhaps). I noticed that when I set the time format in the sheet your shared, it was "00.00.00", not "00:00:00". So, with those regional differences, if you enter a number as "7:24", Sheets may not recognize it as a time.